# Superscript at beginning of annotation with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, superscript

Does anyone have an idea how to start an annotation with superscripted characters? I want to add "208Pb" in which 208 should be given in superscript. With this code:

```
+annotate("text", x=2, y=80, parse = TRUE, label = "^{208}~Pb", angle=90)
```

I only get an error (unexpected '^'). But when i add a letter right before '^' it works fine

```
+annotate("text", x=2, y=80, parse = TRUE, label = "x^{208}~Pb", angle=90)
```

[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7VVk.jpg)

[how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZRu2.jpg)

Do you have an idea how to start with superscripted characters? Thanks very much!

Comment: try `annotate("text", x=2, y=80, parse = TRUE, label = "{}^{208}~Pb", angle=90)`

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much!